# Not show my app in iTunes connect?

Tags: iphone, app-store-connect, itunes

## I Add one app in iTunes but not show in main view![enter image description here

[image]

I already create add new app but not show in main view show in image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I remember right there should be scheduled maintenance for holidays so check your developers account mail for message from Apple.

This probably don't help you but can save some time

Comment: ok,sir 
today i create iTunes account.
thats region to face this problem.